# Swift2 UITest - Wait for element to appear without treating test as Failed in case element won't appear

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode-ui-testing

I try to create UI test on the application where sometimes AD popup appears and if so I need to click on close button. I tried to use:

```
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout: NSTimeInterval, handler: XCWaitCompletionHandler?)
```

with

```
let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
```

But the problem is that the method treats test as failed which is not acceptable for my case.

I tried to use `.exists` after custom `sleep` but from my observations it just always returns `false` even though element does appear on the screen.

Also plaid around with `.hittable` and it seems to be `true` even though the element didn't appear on the screen yet.

From my understanding it would be great if Apple gives control of whether `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` treats test as fail or not, but I was not able to find anything.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you provide the block of your code?

Comment: Here's my code:  `        let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: app.buttons["Close Advertisement"], handler: nil)
        
        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you  not to use handler XCWaitCompletionHandler in this case.

```
expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: evaluatedWithObject, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(TIMEOUT, handler: nil) 
if (evaluatedWithObject.exist) {
//dosmth
}
```

so it is soft assert that smth appears. If element not found it just will wait time and go further

Comment: just tried passing `nil` but still got `Assertion Failure Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 5 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Expect predicate exists == 1 for object.`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only solution I've found is to do it manually: use a while loop and check for object.exists for a waiting period to prevent the expectation wait failure.